# Windows 7 domain clients lock on display sleep

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

We recently deployed a new Windows 7 image to our network. When a user is logged in and idle for 10 minutes the display goes to sleep and requires a password upon waking the display. I don't want the user to have unlock their computer.

I have checked my group policy and local settings and found nothing that points to this.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Client are Windows 7. Server is Windows Server 2012R2

Comment: "I have checked my group policy and local settings" - What settings did you check in your group policy and on the local computer?

Answer (score 0):

You should determine if something is causing this beyond the defaults.

However, you should look at simply controlling these things via GPOs to force what you want as well:

https://superuser.com/questions/1106424/disable-require-password-on-wakeup-through-group-policy

[How to disable screen saver passwords by using policies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272304)

Both of those links will help you out.

However, personally I don't think it's a good idea from a security standpoint to not require a password upon unlock/wake.  You may choose to EXTEND the sleep/lock idle timers and then just ask people to lock their workstations when they leave their desks, but not requiring a password at unlock is a pretty big security hole for most organizations.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree about the security issue, but I don't have a say ;)